# How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16n^2-16n+3}=\frac{\pi}{8}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Wolfram alpha computes

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16n^2-16n+3}=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

But I don't have any idea to prove this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

$$\frac{1}{16n^2-16n+3} = \frac{1}{(4n-1)(4n-3)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac1{4n-1}\right)$$

So $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{16n^2-16n+3} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}$$

That inner series is a [well-known series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) for $\frac{\pi}4$.

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16n^2-16n+3}
&=\frac18\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n-\frac34}-\frac1{n-\frac14}\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\frac18\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{n-7/4}-x^{n-5/4}\right)\,\mathrm dx\tag{2}\\
&=\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(x^{n-7/4}-x^{n-5/4}\right)\,\mathrm dx\tag{3}\\
&=\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^{-3/4}}{1-x}-\frac{x^{-1/4}}{1-x}\right)\,\mathrm dx\tag{4}\\
&=\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^{-3/4}-x^{-1/4}}{1-x}\right)\,\mathrm dx\tag{5}\\
&=\frac18\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right) x^{3/4}}\,\mathrm dx\tag{6}\\
&=\frac18\Bigg[4\arctan \left(\sqrt[4]{x}\right)\Bigg]_{0}^{1}\tag{7}\\
&=\frac\pi8\tag{8}\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{16n^2-16n+3}=\frac\pi8$$